# Need help understanding the Git icons in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git

I'm trying to work through getting my project to commit - but I'm getting errors.

I'm looking at the synchronization perspective and do not understand what all of the file icons mean.  Can someone give me a good reference to tell me what each of the icons mean?

Such as:

- Blue arrow pointing to the left
- Double-red arrow
- White X on red square
- White + over double red arrow
- Blue arrow pointing to the left with a white dash on it
- Exclamation point
- Gray arrow pointing to the right
- Gray arrow pointing to the right with white + sign
- Gray box with white asterisk on it.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can find a good description in the ["Synchronize View" section](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Synchronize_View) of the [Egit manual](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide):

[image: Synch view]

> This state is shown by using icons and can also be configured to show the state as text appended to the resource name.
>
> - [image: d] An incoming addition means that a resource has been added to the target branch.
> - [image: d] An incoming change means that the file has changed in the target branch.
> - [image: d] An incoming deletion means that a resource was deleted from the target branch.
> - [image: d] An outgoing addition means that the file was added to your workspace or source branch and is not yet in the target branch.
> - [image: d] An outgoing change means that the file was changed in your workspace or source branch.
> - [image: d] An outgoing deletion is a resource that has been deleted in your workspace or source branch.
> - [image: d] A conflicting addition means that the resource has been added in your workspace or source branch and in the target branch.
> - [image: d] A conflicting change means that the file has been changed in your workspace or local branch and in the target branch. A manual or automatic merge will be required. Also, any entries in the view that contain children that are conflicts will also be decorated with the conflict icon. This is done to make conflicts easy to find.
> - [image: d] A conflicting deletion means that the resource was deleted in your workspace or source branch and in the target branch.

In your case, keep in mind those overlay icons can appear *in addition* of the [**status** overlay icons](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Icon_Decorations):

[image: status]

That includes:

> - dirty (folder) - At least one file below the folder is dirty; that means that it has changes in the working tree that are neither in the index nor in the repository.
> - tracked - The resource is known to the Git repository and hence under version control.
> - untracked - The resource is not known to the Git repository and will not be version controlled until it is explicitly added.
> - ignored - The resource is ignored by the Git team provider. The preference settings under Team > Ignored Resources, "derived" flag and settings from .gitignore files are taken into account.
> - dirty - The resource has changes in the working tree that are neither in the index nor in the repository.
> - staged - The resource has changes which have been added to the index. Note that adding changes to the index is currently possible only in the commit dialog via the context menu of a resource.
> - partially-staged - The resource has changes which are added to the index and additional changes in the working tree that neither reached the index nor have been committed to the repository. See [partial staging from the Git Staging view](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Partial_Staging) for how to do that.
> - added - The resource has not yet reached any commit in the repository but has been freshly added to the Git repository in order to be tracked in future.
> - removed - The resource is staged for removal from the Git repository.
> - conflict - A merge conflict exists for the file.
> - assume-valid - The resource has the "assume unchanged" flag. This means that Git stops checking the working tree files for possible modifications, so you need to manually unset the bit to tell Git when you change the working tree file. Also see [Assume unchanged action](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Menu_Actions).